# What is the difference between a ChannelHandler storing state in instance fields and one using attributes?

Tags: netty

I have a `ChannelHandler` implementation that currently sets an instance field when an `HttpRequest` message is received, and uses that field when an `HttpContent` message is received, and `null`s out the field when a `LastHttpContent` message is received.  The `ChannelHandler` implementation class is consequently not annotated with `@Sharable`.

What would happen if I placed this state in an attribute instead of an instance field?  Is there any significant difference?  I assume this still would not allow my `ChannelHandler` implementation to be sharable?

(Using Netty 4.1.36.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instance field over and attribute if the state will only be accessed from the same ChannelHandler. If you need to set the state in one handler but access in others an attribute is a good fit.

Comment: But to be clear, simply moving state to an attribute does not then necessarily thereby permit the `ChannelHandler` to be sharable, correct?

Comment: as the attribute is per Context or per Channel it is safe to share it as these are not shared across connections and so threads.

Comment: So it would still seem that for my use case, described in detail above, I have no choice but to use instance variables.  Is that correct?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: no both will work that said the instance field is the better fit imho

Comment: Thank you; so I could apply `@Sharable` even with instance variables here?

Comment: Only if the instance variable is thread-safe and meant to be used concurrently... Like for example an AtomicLong to count the connections.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. As long as your handler contains no state, you can annotate it with `@Sharable` and only create one instance of it. In turn, your `ChannelInitializer` can add that instance to each new `Channel` rather than creating a new instance for each connection.

Comment: Thank you; to be clear, if I move the state from an instance field to an attribute, there is no difference in functionality or state scope?  It is an absolutely-equivalent-in-all-respects change?  To ask it another way: is there ever _any_ advantage to storing state in an instance field, then?

Comment: storing in an instance field is usually preferred as it will take less memory and also is faster to access then an attribute.